# How conserved quantities lead to equations of motion in Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

In a classical mechanics exercise, we were asked to derive a system of ODEs from conserved quantities. As we know from Lagrangian mechanics, Euler-Lagrange equations lead to equations of motion.

I understand that from E-L, we could resolve the equation of motion to understand the movement of the particle.

However, how can we deduce the motion from conserved quantities ?

In particular, I had these three conserved quantities,
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  I = m\dot{x} - e(Et - By) \equiv I_x \\
  p_y = m\dot{y} - eBx \equiv I_y \\
  p_z = m\dot{z} \equiv I_z
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Where $E$ and $B$ are constant electric and magnetic field.

Comment: who claims that you can deduce motion from conserved quantities?

Comment: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240400/84967)'s an example.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Since it is rather straightforward to derive Newton's laws from conservation of momentum, and rather less straightforward but still possible, to derive Maxwell's equations in the context of relativistic quantum mechanics, then I should have thought that all true physicists would make this claim. The question here is how to do it in the context of Lagrangian mechanics, which I will not answer because I do not think that either mathematics or science should be about making things unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I don't know if I'd say you can deduce *motion* from conservation of charge, for example.  I think one can derive a 1-parameter subgroup of the phase space from the conserved quantity, but perhaps one shouldn't call it a motion.

Comment: I'm wondering a little about that $t$ in the first quantity.  I thought "constant field" would have meant it was the same in the region in question, or the same at each location over time, or both.  Can you clarify?

Comment: If it is the same over time, but different based on location, then what would be the meaning of $Et$?